# Request again with a different proxy when one request fail

Tags: python, scrapy

I use a pool of proxies, so each request is assigned a different proxy, with a code similar to this:

```
class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "my_spider"
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MySpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.proxy_pool = ['proxy_address1', 'proxy_address2', ..., 'proxy_addressN']

    def parse(self, response):
        ...parse code...
        if something:
            yield self.get_request(url)

    def get_request(self, url):
        req = Request(url=url)
        if self.proxy_pool:
            req.meta['proxy'] = random.choice(self.proxy_pool)
        return req
```

The problem is when a bad proxy appears and connection fails, the implied webpage will be missing. I want to restart the failed requests with a different proxy.

Can it be done with a middleware?

Comment: What do you mean by middleware?

Comment: @ThatBird https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html

Comment: There's a rather popular middleware that does exactly this: https://github.com/TeamHG-Memex/scrapy-rotating-proxies